# Laravel how to forceDelete all related models with parent?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to force delete model with one relation. I made a custom function for that in model.

```
    /**
     * Force delete active ingredient with relationships
     * @return bool|null
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function bruteDelete()
    {
        $this->brandPresentations()->forceDelete();
        return parent::forceDelete();
    }
```

This is how I am calling the function

```
Active_ingredients::withTrashed()->find($request->get('elementID'))->bruteDelete();
```

Which force deletes `brandPresentations` perfectly. But it soft deletes the parent, which is `active_ingredients`.

I tried to use forceDelete() as function name to overwrite the Laravel method, but it gave me the same result.
How can I force delete both models?

Comment: Did you use `$this-> forceDelete()` instead of `parent::forceDelete()`?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin tried both

Comment: Would really like to know the answer as to why this *doesn't* work

Comment: @MrCarrot I still don't know why this did not work, but the methods down in the answers works perfectly! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it in `boot` method like this.

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::deleting(function (User $model) {
        if ($model->forceDeleting){
            $model->brandPresentations()->forceDelete();
        }
    });
}
```

And then run `forceDelete`

```
Active_ingredients::withTrashed()->find($request->get('elementID'))->forceDelete();
```

I hope it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using cascade on delete for your migrations

`$table->foreign('model_id')->references('id')->on('models')->onDelete('cascade');`

By calling `$item->forceDelete()` then all of its related foreign keys would be deleted as well.
I'm pretty sure this does not work for soft delete.